# Find deep nested array depth

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, nested

I have a nested array. Like below:
I want to find the depth of this nested array, which means the child element has most deep nested children.

```
let arr = [
   {
     name: 'tiger',
     children: [{
       name: 'sinba',
       children: [{
         name: 'cute',
         children: []
        }]
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'lion',
      children: []
    }
]
```

In this case, the depth is **3**, the `tiger` has 3 level. So the depth is 3

How could i achieve this? I try to use recursive, but don't know how to find the element which
has most nested children.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that there are no circular references, you could try something like this

```js
let arr = [{
    name: 'tiger',
    children: [{
      name: 'sinba',
      children: [{
        name: 'cute',
        children: []
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    name: 'lion',
    children: []
  }
]

function count(children) {
  return children.reduce((depth, child) => {
    return Math.max(depth, 1 + count(child.children)); // increment depth of children by 1, and compare it with accumulated depth of other children within the same element
  }, 0); //default value 0 that's returned if there are no children
}

console.log(count(arr))
```

Our function would not work if there were some circular references, so there might be a need to adjust it accordingly. Detecting circular references is a whole ordeal. If nothing is done about it, the function will throw a Maximum call stack size exceeded error.

In order to handle it without any additional functionality implementation you could use already existing native `JSON.stringify` to do so. The stringify option will throw an exception only if you try to serialize `BigInt` values which we can handle ourselves or when objects are cyclic, which is excatly what we wanted.

```js
let arr = [{
  name: 'tiger',
  children: []
}]

function testCircular(arr){
  try {
    BigInt.prototype.toJSON = function() { return this.toString() } // Instead of throwing, JSON.stringify of BigInt now produces a string
    JSON.stringify(arr);
    return false;
  }
  catch (e) {
    // will only enter here in case of circular references
    return true;
  }
}

function count(children) {
  if (testCircular(children)) return Infinity;
  return children.reduce((depth, child) => {
    return Math.max(depth, 1 + count(child.children)); // increment depth of children by 1, and compare it with accumulated depth of other children within the same element
  }, 0); //default value 0 that's returned if there are no children
}

console.log(count(arr)) // normally counting
arr[0].children = arr; // creates circular reference
console.log(count(arr)) // counting for circular
```

Comment: why the `Math.max` and comparing ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee reduce function iterated over all children elements, I need to compare results of counting children of children with each other to know which one has the most and only keep information on it. Granted i only compare at most 2 elements at a time i could probably use a simple if else statement, but max works just as well

Comment: Nice solution !

Comment: note the `BigInt` extension will not `JSON.parse` large numbers back to `BigInt`. Eg `JSON.parse("999999999999999999999999999999999999999999")` returns `1e+42`

Comment: here it's only used to remove the error throwing not to actually parse the data